# How to force the unbreak of a single footnote?

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, bigfoot

I am in the final phase of the document preparation, so I'm quite sure that pages will not change before printing.

I noticed that, for some strange reason, `bigfoot` breaks some footnotes across pages, even if there is enough normal text below the last footnotemark in the page (so that I would expect that it would have moved some normal text to the next page, thus allowing footnotetext fit within the same page).

Do you know if it is possible to locally force a single footnotetext to be unbreakable? If possible, I'd avoid to change global penalties in the preamble, because other problems may arise in other document points...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

As I already answered to your crosspost [Unbreak single footnote](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22933) on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/), there's a possible workaround, try if it's ok for you:

```
\let\origfootnote\footnote
\usepackage{bigfoot}
```

and later in the code, for the single unbreakable footnote, you could use the `\origfootnote` command. I checked with an example that the page break would not occur and the numbering still matches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\origfootnote\footnote
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext[5]
\clearpage
\blindtext[5]
\origfootnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext[5]
\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```